# Dynamodb GSI containing boolean

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, database-administration

I have a dynamodb table of events that have specified start and end times. These events can be happening in realtime, in which case, the end timestamp is not yet written.

I have setup a global secondary index with the sort key being the binary field, `active`. When I try and update a record to set this to true, I get the error:

```
Expected: B Actual: BOOL
```

The python code for this is:

```
table.update_item(
    Key={
        'fingerprint': item['fingerprint'],
        'startedtimestamp': item['startedtimestamp']
    },
    UpdateExpression="SET #active :active, resolvedtimestamp :resolvedtimestamp",
    ExpressionAttributeNames : {
        '#active' : 'active',
        '#resolvedtimestamp' : 'resolvedtimestamp'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':active': False, ':resolvedtimestamp': resolvedtimestamp},
)
```

I have also been reading elsewhere about using a sparse index instead. In this case though, if the index was just the `resolvedtimestamp`, would it be possible to query for the active records (e.g. `resolvedtimestamp` is not set)? Otherwise, what other optimizations can I do to the table and indices to be able to query for active records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have setup a global secondary index with the sort key being the binary field, `active`

`active` is a boolean not a binary field and that is why you receive the exception. Also, it's not possible to use boolean as part of a primary key, it must be string, number or binary.

If you are only interested in active records, then set `active = 'True'` only when true, do not set it to false. If false, delete the attribute from the item. This will give you a sparse index.

```
table.update_item(
    Key={
        'fingerprint': item['fingerprint'],
        'startedtimestamp': item['startedtimestamp']
    },
    UpdateExpression="SET #active = :active, resolvedtimestamp = :resolvedtimestamp",
    ExpressionAttributeNames : {
        '#active' : 'active',
        '#resolvedtimestamp' : 'resolvedtimestamp'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':active': 'True', 
        ':resolvedtimestamp': resolvedtimestamp},
)
```

Comment: Thanks Lee! I mistook 'B' for Boolean but have now realized they are different.

Comment: Would you recommend just using the resolvedtimestamp in the GSI? Can I query for the GSI == NULL to get the active records?

Comment: I recommend using a sparse GSI where the partition or sort key is for the `active` attribute. Only store that value if it's true and make sure it's a string, not bool. The GSI will only then contain active items.

Answer (score -1):

Please update your Update Expression with.

```py
 UpdateExpression="SET #active = :active, resolvedtimestamp = :resolvedtimestamp",
```